# C# Automapper "Unsupported Mapping" with List<dynamic> result of LinQ query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, automapper

Given the next working LinQ query:

```
var catalogues = (from cat in db.CATALOGUES

                      join doc in db.DOCUMENTS_CATALOGS on
                      new { a = cat.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = cat.FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO }
                      equals
                      new { a = doc.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = (int?)doc.PK_DOCUMENT }

                      join pos in db.DOCUMENTS_CATALOGS on
                      new { a = cat.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = cat.FK_DOCUMENT }
                      equals
                      new { a = pos.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = (int?)pos.PK_DOCUMENT }

                      where (cat.PFK_ENTERPRISE == enterpriseId && cat.PK_CATALOGUE == catalogueId)
                      orderby cat.DESC_CATALOGUE ascending
                      select new
                      {
                          cat.PK_CATALOGUE,
                          cat.FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO,
                          cat.DESC_CATALOGUE,
                          doc.REAL_NAME,
                          doc.SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE,
                          POSTER = pos.SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE
                      });
```

Which produces a result with a List Anonymous with something like this (1 record un my case):

```
{ 
    PK_CATALOGUE = 212, 
    FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO = 212, 
    DESC_CATALOGUE = "xxx", 
    REAL_NAME = "7_Category_Image_c3ab57e3-ec7e-4a80-aaa1-c6cc10a1b917.jpg", 
    SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE = "7_Category_Image_c3ab57e3-ec7e-4a80-aaa1-c6cc10a1b917.jpg", 
    POSTER = "7_IMG_CATALOGUE_5d8e24eb-8a40-4e4d-9d86-a3f610d5b65e.jpg" 
}
```

I'm trying to map it to the next object:

```
public class VideoGalleryVM
{
    public int PK_CATALOGUE { get; set; }
    public int? FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO { get; set; }
    public string DESC_CATALOGUE { get; set; }
    public string REAL_NAME { get; set; }
    public string SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE { get; set; }
    public string POSTER { get; set; }
}
```

The following way:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<object, VideoTrainingVM>().ReverseMap();
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

List<VideoGalleryVM> vgVM = mapper.Map<List<VideoGalleryVM>>(videoGallery);
```

But I whatever I try I get an exception of type "Invalid mapping".

I don't mind using Automapper or not, just need to cast the return of the LinQ query (that is List dynamic) to a View Model object, and:

```
var test1 = catalogues.ToList().Cast<VideoGalleryVM1>().ToList();
```

ends with an invalid cast Exception and

```
var test2 = catalogues.OfType<VideoGalleryVM1>().ToList();
```

ends with a list of 0 elements.

Comment: Just use `VideoGalleryVM` instead of the anonymous object.

Comment: Thatks @Lucian Bargaoanu, but where? You mean instead of var in LinQ query? If instead of var I use List<VideoGalleryVM> the compiler complains and marks all the query in red saying it cannot convert blahblah blah :s

Comment: You need to provide the property name: `new VideoGalleryVM { PK_CATALOGUE = cat.PK_CATALOGUE, ... }`

Comment: Already tried that @Yong Shun, but always get "MappingException". Also tried var abc = catalogues.OfType<VideoGalleryVM>().ToList(); and this won't crash, but gives a list of 0 elements.

Comment: If I try var test = catalogues.ToList().Cast<VideoGalleryVM1>().ToList(); I get {"No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo '<>f__AnonymousType3`6[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]' al tipo 'ADMGroup.Framework.Domain.Catalogues.Repositories.VideoGalleryVM1'."} ... And the types are just the same!! I'm lost.

Comment: Since `catalogues` returns `List<VideoGalleryVM>`, you don't need to use AutoMapper for mapping. If this doesn't help, please share your code on how you map and map with what value.

Comment: I have var catalogues = ... LinQ ... if I put List<VideoGalleryVM> catalogues = ... LinQ .... it won't compile @Yong Shun. I don't mind using Automapper or not, I need the LinQ query result to be of type List<VideoGalleryVM>, but always get a cast exception...

Comment: It seems tha you dont need any configuration in automapper to map dynamic objects: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: If I write Mapper.Map<List<VideoGalleryVM>>(videoGallery); I also get a Mapper exception @Fabio Cavallari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need Automapper for everything, it was created for simple scenarios - mapping similar KNOWN objects to another and better if mapping is simple. If you make projection via `Select` - you can map all that you need in one place without using "magic" of Automapper.

So just project your result into desired objet type:

```cs
var catalogues = 
    from cat in db.CATALOGUES

    join doc in db.DOCUMENTS_CATALOGS on
    new { a = cat.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = cat.FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO }
    equals
    new { a = doc.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = (int?)doc.PK_DOCUMENT }

    join pos in db.DOCUMENTS_CATALOGS on
    new { a = cat.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = cat.FK_DOCUMENT }
    equals
    new { a = pos.PFK_ENTERPRISE, b = (int?)pos.PK_DOCUMENT }

    where (cat.PFK_ENTERPRISE == enterpriseId && cat.PK_CATALOGUE == catalogueId)
    orderby cat.DESC_CATALOGUE ascending
    select new VideoGalleryVM
    {
        PK_CATALOGUE = cat.PK_CATALOGUE,
        FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO = cat.FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO,
        DESC_CATALOGUE = cat.DESC_CATALOGUE,
        REAL_NAME = doc.REAL_NAME,
        SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE = doc.SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE,
        POSTER = pos.SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE
    };
```

Highly recommend to read article from Automapperr's creator when to use or not his library. Article was created to stop using library for cases when it is a pain to support mapping later: [AutoMapper Usage Guidelines](https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/)

Comment: `ProjecTo` would certainly help here :) Because the names are the same. But you wouldn't write _this_ query. You would use the navigation properties.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, probably article is for you ;) Automapper for everything.

Comment: I'm talking about this here. A text book case for `ProjectTo`. So maybe read that again? :)

Comment: You can apply ProjectTo only if you successfully created mapping. As you mentioned, without navigation properties it is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I've found to cast my List of dynamic (result of LinQ query) to a View Model object was:

```
var targetList = catalogues.Select(cat => new VideoGalleryVM() 
                { 
                    PK_CATALOGUE = cat.PK_CATALOGUE,
                    FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO = cat.FK_DOCUMENT_VIDEO,
                    DESC_CATALOGUE = cat.DESC_CATALOGUE,
                    REAL_NAME = cat.REAL_NAME,
                    SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE = cat.SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE,
                    POSTER = cat.SERVER_NAME_ORIGINAL_FILE
                }).ToList();
```

I don't think is the best option, not even understand why Automapper (or other type of casts) won't work, but this just works.

In my case we are talking of a class with not so many properties, but image a long class... this is what Automapper is supposed to.

Comment: Not my minus. I do not see any reason to use AM in your case. You can do `new VideoGalleryVM() { ... }` exactly when building `catalogues`. And this is the right way.

Comment: Thank you @Svyatoslav Danyliv, it worked, if you write is as an answer I'll marke it as correct.